# angular js 2nd controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with the 2nd controller(RegisterController) I've defined in my module. The first one works fine though.
I have 2 controllers in a file named user.js

```js
var app = angular.module("User", []);
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
      email: 'bbb@ccc.com',
      password: '',
      username: 'sex',
    };
    $scope.login = function() {
      return $http.post('http://localhost/cw/index.php/rest/resource/user/action/login', $scope.user).then(function successCallback(response) {
        if (response.data.success == 'true') {

        }

      }, function errorCallback(response) {

      });;

    }

  }
]);
app.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
      email: 'abc@123.com',
      password1: 'lol',
      password2: '',
      username: 'blah',
      profile_picture: '',
      dobDay: '',
      dobMonth: '',
      dobYear: '',
    };
    $scope.submit = function() {
      alert("submit");

    }
  }
]);
```

And my html looks like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>
                        <table style="text-align: right" ng-app="User" ng-controller="LoginController">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Email
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" ng-bind="user.email" ng-model="user.email">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Password
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" ng-bind="user.password" ng-model="user.password">
                                </td>    
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td></td>
                               <td style="float:left">
                                    <button ng-click="login()">login</button>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                    </span>

    </td>

    <td>
      <div style="border-left:1px solid">
        <table style="text-align: left" ng-app="User" ng-controller="RegisterController">
          <tr>
            <td>
              Username
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-bind="user.username" ng-model="user.username">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Email
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="email" ng-bind="user.email" ng-model="user.email">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Password
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-bind="user.password1" ng-model="user.email">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Retype password
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-bind="user.password2" ng-model="user.password">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Date of Birth
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobDay" ng-model="user.password" value="DD" size="2" maxlength="2">
              <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobMonth" ng-model="user.password" value="MM" size="2" maxlength="2">
              <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobYear" ng-model="user.password" value="YYYY" size="4" maxlength="4">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Profile picture
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="file" ng-bind="profile_picture">

            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td style="float:left">
              <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Even the button click does nothing. What is the problem here?
I'm new to Angular js. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which controller not work?

Comment: its the one at the bottom. RegisterController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- insert your `ng-app="User"` inot table element

  - remove other `ng-app="User"` instances.
  - you can define `ng-app` only once for using no of controllers.

```js
var app = angular.module("User", []);
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
      email: 'bbb@ccc.com',
      password: '',
      username: 'sex',
    };
    $scope.login = function() {
      return $http.post('http://localhost/cw/index.php/rest/resource/user/action/login', $scope.user).then(function successCallback(response) {
        if (response.data.success == 'true') {

        }

      }, function errorCallback(response) {

      });;

    }

  }
]);
app.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {
      email: 'abc@123.com',
      password1: 'lol',
      password2: '',
      username: 'blah',
      profile_picture: '',
      dobDay: '',
      dobMonth: '',
      dobYear: '',
    };
    $scope.submit = function() {
      alert("submit");

    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="User">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>
                        <table style="text-align: right"  ng-controller="LoginController">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Email
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" ng-bind="user.email" ng-model="user.email">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Password
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" ng-bind="user.password" ng-model="user.password">
                                </td>    
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td></td>
                               <td style="float:left">
                                    <button ng-click="login()">login</button>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
                    </span>

      </td>

      <td>
        <div style="border-left:1px solid">
          <table style="text-align: left" ng-controller="RegisterController">
            <tr>
              <td>
                Username
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-bind="user.username" ng-model="user.username">
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Email
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="email" ng-bind="user.email" ng-model="user.email">
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Password
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-bind="user.password1" ng-model="user.email">
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Retype password
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-bind="user.password2" ng-model="user.password">
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Date of Birth
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobDay" ng-model="user.password" value="DD" size="2" maxlength="2">
                <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobMonth" ng-model="user.password" value="MM" size="2" maxlength="2">
                <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobYear" ng-model="user.password" value="YYYY" size="4" maxlength="4">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Profile picture
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="file" ng-bind="profile_picture">

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td style="float:left">
                <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</div>
```